# How to use getElementByClassName in the javascript to add the checkboxes in the two lists having same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two lists with same class name...i want to create checkboxes in this list dynamically from XML.

Now My problem is, How to use getElementByClassName in the javascript to add the checkboxes in the two lists having same class name.

My codings are below...

**My Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("value");

    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
     var name=x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
     var cb = document.createElement( "input" );
     cb.type = "li";
     cb.id = "c1";
     cb.value = name;
     cb.checked = true;
     document.getElementByClassName("list1").appendChild( cb ); 
     }

</script>
```

**My HTML:**

My First List

My second List

If i try this it shows error as, getElementByClassName is not a function....

How to create checkboxes in the above tow list using Class name....

Please help me....

Comment: Any reason you aren't/don't want to use `jQuery`?

Comment: he tagged it as jquery. i don;t see why you can't answer with it.

Comment: Hmm, I guess. I'm having a hard time where the problem in his code is, specifically, where he is adding the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
document.getElementByClassName("list1").appendChild(cb);
```

if that is where you are adding the checkboxes, I'm having a hard time finding it, use

```
$('.list1').each(function() {
    $(this).append(cb);
});
```

**EDIT**

You said `If i try this it shows error as, getElementByClassName is not a function....`. You need to use `getElementsByClassName` (notice the `s` on `element`) instead!

Comment: I have tried like You said...List scroll bars are displayed....But list items are not displayed..it shows empty.....what is the problem here....